# Python3 program execution failing with error: 'socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'

Tags: python, urllib3

I am running a python3 program using python virtualenv.
I am behind proxy and have exported the http_proxy/https_proxy before executing the below program. still running into issues. Please suggest.

```
(geo_env)root@xyz-ntp-154:~/geo_env# cat search1.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pygeocoder import Geocoder

if __name__ == '__main__':
    address = '207 N. Defiance St, Archbold, OH'
    print(Geocoder.geocode(address)[0].coordinates)
```

Here is the error:

```
(geo_env)root@xyz-ntp-154:~/geo_env# python3 search1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/geo_env/lib/python3.4/site-    packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
File "/root/geo_env/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 67, in create_connection
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Can you make plain http requests without the Geocoder?